# How to return NSDictionary in swift, while waiting for its value to be set?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

please spare me. Im new to swift

my problem was I cant return my NSDictionary this is my function

```
   private func request(url:String, baseURL:String) -> NSDictionary {
       var dict:NSDictionary!
        var request = HTTPTask()
        request.requestSerializer = HTTPRequestSerializer()
        request.requestSerializer.headers[headerKey] = getToken() //example of adding a header value

        request.baseURL = baseURL

        request.GET(url, parameters: nil, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
            if var data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
                let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                var error: NSError?
                dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
              println("response: \(dict)") 
            }
            },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                println("error: \(error)")
        })

       return dict 
    }
```

the return dict is just empty like `{}` but when i `println("response: \(dict)")` inside the function seem to log my data.

I think my function return an empty object because the .GET method is running in different thread and waiting for a response.

Could anyone help me, any comment would do.

Comment: as you have see you can't do it in that way you, instead of returning a value from the function you will have to create a delegate or send a closure to the function to be executed once the request finish

Comment: oh i see, Im not been on that part yet or maybe I am but not that much. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, request runs asynchronously in another thread, I would suggest using completion handler.

```
private func request(url: String, baseURL: String, completion: (result: NSDictionary) -> Void) {

    var dict:NSDictionary!
    var request = HTTPTask()
    request.requestSerializer = HTTPRequestSerializer()
    request.requestSerializer.headers[headerKey] = getToken() //example of adding a header value

    request.baseURL = baseURL

    request.GET(url, parameters: nil, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
        if var data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var error: NSError?
            dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
          println("response: \(dict)")
          completion(result: dict) 
        }
        },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
            println("error: \(error)")
            completion(result: nil) //this is not the best option, better would be to return error in error handler
    })
}
```

For more info check out this: http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/1/13/completion-handlers-swift-programming-tutorial

Comment: was this a callback? maybe it would do.I'll try it